MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite)
i'm stuck with this error "MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadModel on channel tflite)" while using tensorflow lite on flutter, i use the latest version of tflite ^1.1.2 and my model path is correct ... this is my loading code :
void loadModel() async {
    try {
      print("Attempting to load model...");
      String? res = await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/model.tflite",
        labels: "assets/labels.txt",
      );
      if (res == null || res.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception("Failed to load model");
      }
      print("Result of loadModel: $res");
      setState(() {
        isModelLoaded = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading model: $e");
    }
  }

i use the latest version of tflite ^1.1.2 and my model path is correct

Don't do a hot reload after adding a plugin which adds native functionality. Close the app and restart it.

If you are facing this problem in the release build, add ProGuard rules so that native code is not shaken out on release.

yeaah I have some problem too, the librarry is kinda not mature.
